# How to check whether a specific service exists using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, services

**Introduction**

According to [this documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176858.aspx) it is possible to check which services have been stopped on Windows by executing the following command:

`Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.status -eq "stopped"}`

in PowerShell.

**Question**

Which command needs to be issued in PowerShell in order to check whether a certain service, e.g. tomcat8 exists?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can specify the service name using the `-Name` attribute. By default if it doesn't see a matching service it will give an error. Using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` you can get an empty variable back.

```
$service = Get-Service -Name W32Time -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Once you have that you can just see if the length is greater than 0.

```
if ($service.Length -gt 0) {
    # Do cool stuff
    }
```

Comment: Snippets from the answer have been combined in a ps1 file and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

This is a slightly cleaner solution than the accepted answer:

```
$service = Get-Service -Name MSSQLSERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if($service -eq $null)
{
    # Service does not exist
} else {
    # Service does exist
}
```

In my opinion, checking it for NULL makes more sense semantically than checking for the length property.

This is tested and working in this version of PowerShell:

```
Major  Minor  Patch  PreReleaseLabel BuildLabel
-----  -----  -----  --------------- ----------
7      0      3
```

I cannot speak to other versions of PowerShell, but please comment if you have issues.

Comment: I agree that comparing to $null is the "Powershellesque" way to do this! However, for comparisons to $null in Powershell, always put $null on the left-hand side. If you don't, you might not get the result you expect. You can find lots of discussion about this by searching for something like "Powershell compare null left". Here is one example, from StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58217913/should-null-be-on-the-left-side-of-the-equality-comparison-eq-with-arrays Unbelievably, this absolutely matters in Powershell.

Comment: @chris that link you provided only applies to arrays. You would have to worry if you performed a like match - e.g. `Get-Service *s*`, but in this case, it's only possible for either a `System.ComponentModel.Component.ServiceController` or `null` to return. In windows, you cannot register two services with the exact same name.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, and you are right. I didn't think that through. But I think that there's still a problem. If we put code on the Internet showing people how to use Powershell, and they haven't learned this about Powershell yet, they are likely to _always_ use `$something -eq $null` and eventually that will bite them. Even here, if my goal is to see whether _any_ SQL service is installed, and I say `Get-Service *sql*`, this will fail. That's why the `$null -eq $something` pattern is a best practice. I think we should always use it when posting to protect new Powershellers.

Comment: @chris Still not understanding your argument `$services = Get-Service *sql*` `$services -eq $null` returns true...

Comment: (1/2) @kolob. part of what I'm saying is that it's just a well-known community best practice. People are used to seeing "variable == constant" so much, and $null is a constant, that they will default to "variable -eq $null" and eventually have problems and probably wonder why. You can easily see this by searching for powershell/null/left.

Comment: (2/2) @kolob, I *do* have SQL installed, so `Get-Service *sql*` returns 14 items. However, `$null -eq $(Get-Service *sql*)` correctly yields `false` but `$null -eq $(Get-Service *sql*)` returns nothing at all.

Consider that we are having an extended online discussion about this, but it seems you didn't quite catch a valid counterexample to your claim. This particular test should ALWAYS be done with `$null` on the left. You thought you showed this wasn't true. Remember my claim that putting `$null` on the right will eventually bite people? I think it just happened to you. ;)

Comment: OK, this is (3/2) @kolob :D if you use the VSCode Powershell extensions, PSScriptAnalyzer suggests putting `$null` on the left. It's wrong to ALWAYS put `$null` on either the right or the left, and I think this was part of your original point. But the reason that "left" is a suggestion in PSScriptAnalyzer, and that people don't complain much about the (valid) exceptions, seems simple to me: `$null` on the left is at least as safe as `$null` on the right by a very wide margin. The opposite case is not true, and the SQL example shows how easily smart folks can make the mistake.

Comment: @dkolb, in my "2/2" comment, I have a typo. It looks like I can't edit the comment so I'll just call it out here. The part about how one command correction yields false but another command returns nothing at all is wrong because I posted the same command twice! This is what it should have said:

> However, `$null -eq $(Get-Service *sql*)` correctly yields false but `$(Get-Service *sql*) -eq $null` returns nothing at all.

Comment: I just posted another comment where I correct that mistake. It's an example of where `$null` on the left yields `false` (which is correct), but `$null` on the right yields nothing at all, which is an incorrect answer.

Comment: If the service is marked for deletion for any reason, when you run `$service = Get-Service -Name MSSQLSERVER -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, $service will not be $null it will still show as installed. Something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

Providing the service DHCP in fact exists, using $(Get-Service dhcp) -eq $null will return false. However, $(Get-Service dhcp) -ne $null will return true

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).